# Add custom fields to existing posts (admin pages)

Tags: custom-field

I'm able to add a custom field for new posts (in the admin pages), using the action hook `wp_insert_post`. But I would like to add the custom field for old posts, when I am editing the post (in the admin pages), there is any action hook to do that ?

Sample code that I'm using:

```
 /**
 * Default custom field for Municipi
 * @param [type] $post_ID [description]
 */
function set_default_custom_field_municipi($post_ID){
    $municipi = get_post_meta($post_ID,'municipi',true);
    $default_meta = ''; // value

    add_post_meta($post_ID,'municipi',$default_meta,true);

    return $post_ID;
}

/** add custom fields by default */
add_action('wp_insert_post','set_default_custom_field_municipi');
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Andreas Krischer suggested, I fixed using an script to update all the old values and then only using the `wp_insert_post` to create the custom field for the new posts.

The script that I used:

```
INSERT INTO wp_postmeta( post_id, meta_key, meta_value ) 
SELECT wp_posts.ID,  'municipi',  ''
FROM wp_posts
WHERE wp_posts.post_status =  'publish'
AND wp_posts.post_type =  'post'
```

Here I'm updating all the posts that are with the status publish and are type post, and I'm creating a custom field called `municipi` with initial value empty.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a template for custom fields related to the post type.
You can add a meta box and add custom fields:

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'gp_add_meta_boxes' );
function gp_add_meta_boxes() {
    add_meta_box( 'gp_product', 'Products Options', 'gp_products_callback', 'products', 'normal', 'high' );
}

function gp_products_callback( $post ) {
    $fname = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'fname', true );
    $lname = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'lname', true );
    ?>
    <p>First Name: <input type="text" name="fname" value="<?php echo $fname; ?>"></p>
    <p>Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname" value="<?php echo $lname; ?>"></p>
    <?php
}
```

In the example above, you can add input of different types according to what you need.

Comment: Custom fields already have its own meta box. It is hidden by default. You can unhide it by clicking its check box under "Screen Options". For custom post types, you need to include `custom-fields` in your `supports` parameter

Comment: I think eballo needs a way to avoid that every editor add custom fields that have different slug, foe ex. name or fname or firstname for the name. If you create a custom meta box and exclude the standard one the above scenario is excluded.

Comment: @GiovanniPutignano I guess this is only the way to display the custom fields right ? but I will still have the problem for the old ones, and I need to use the script that I posted right ?

Comment: @eballo I think that in this way you don't need to add values for all posts if they are empty. If you edit an old post than you can add the right value for custom fields if you need. You have to add only fields that are necessary.